# system tray icon not displaying on startup of program

Tags: java, system-tray

I used following code for display system tray icon and message. Startup message and tooltip message is displayed well. But tray icon is not displaying. The icon is in images folder. How can i solve this problem ?

```
    public void systemTray() {
    try {
        SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Reg Member MO.png"));
        Image image = icon.getImage();
        TrayIcon icn = new TrayIcon(image, "This is demonstration system tray");
        icn.setToolTip("Now you can see system tray\ntooltip here\nThis is demonstration system tray ToolTip");
        tray.add(icn);     
        icn.displayMessage("This is demonstration System Tray message", "You can add some text to\ndisplay here as System Tray Message", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StartupSystemTray.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your icon image is too large than allocated space. Try using `public void setImageAutoSize(boolean autosize)` method as `icn.setImageAutoSize(true)`. This will re-size the image.